# Error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main progress: com.example.myapplication

Tags: java, android-studio

app keeps crashing for unknown reasons. What can I do?
(If you need more info, please tell)

logcat:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7375
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3686)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3823)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8285)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8264)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3823) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2306) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is the code in question
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(androidx.core.R.id.action_container,homeFragment).commit();

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

Comment: @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(androidx.core.R.id.action_container,homeFragment).commit();
                        return true;

Comment: case R.id.club:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(androidx.core.R.id.action_container,partyFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.user:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(androidx.core.R.id.action_container,userFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).